# Bigquery: cannot keep field description

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've created an empty table in Bigquery:

```
import bigquery 

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField(name="id", 
                         field_type="INTEGER", 
                         description='user ID',
                         mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField(name="field1", 
                         field_type="INTEGER", 
                         description='my field 1',
                         mode="NULLABLE")
]
table = bigquery.Table('myproject.mydataset.mytable', schema=schema)
table.description="A test table."
table.expires=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
table.labels={"label": "mylabel"}


table = bq_client.create_table(table)
```

However when I add new data in `WRITE_TRUNCATE` mode, the field descriptions are lost and all fields become `NULLABLE`

```
table_id='myproject.mydataset.mytable'
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id, write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE')

query_job = bq_client.query("SELECT * FROM my_other_table", job_config=job_config)

query_job.result()  

table = bigquery.Table('myproject.mydataset.mytable')
table.schema = schema
table = bq_client.update_table(table, ["schema"])

print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

How to keep the description in the schema fields, as well as the type `REQUIRED` while writing to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Per StackOverflow post you can use CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE instead of WRITE_TRUNCATE with SELECT to keep the column descriptions. You can also use DELETE FROM table WHERE true; INSERT INTO table SELECT… if you don’t want to repeat the column description in every scheduled query.